# Simple ListLiew with 2 columns?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to setup a simple listview with 2 columns, I would just like it to hold a name and age. I think may be able to use a grid view, but i don't know how many names it will need to hold, and if grid views are scrollable or not. I apologize about my code I have got 1 column listviews to work fine a few different ways, and am all over the place now. I am just putting something so you guys don't think i didn't try, I have been stuck for a day and a half now, and I'm not getting anywhere. I am have trouble finding a good example of a simple multiple column listview example anywhere.

```
     ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              R.layout.list11, minu);

              ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.country_list);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);









<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
     android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fskdumnn"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:background="#CC0000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

     </LinearLayout>




     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fsvumnn"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:background="#CC0000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6" >



            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tekxw1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jmnxx"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:shadowDx="1.6"
            android:shadowDy="1.6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:shadowRadius="2.0"
            android:shadowColor="#FFADD6"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jcxxx"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="44"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Age"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jcfxx"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>


      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fhfdmnn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="#ED69AB"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jmacxsnxx"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
           android:background="#CC0000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


           <ListView
           android:id="@+id/country_list"
           android:layout_weight="96"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          </ListView>




     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jmbfcnxx"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:background="#CC0000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




     </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: @Sharj Uh no? He's looking for a Custom ListView. Look it up. I think a custom listView is what you're looking for. It's a bit more work compared to a ListView but it gets the job done for you.

Comment: @Sharj thanks i will check out the grid view, never used it before.

Comment: @Razgriz it don't matter to me as long as it's scrollable and has  2 columns and is clickable, I think it will work for me. Just want to display something like name and age, and let them click on it.

Comment: @user3705179 okay, I'm now writing an answer. Hopefully it helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a Custom ListView. It is basically a listView but you provide your own row layout (therefore, giving you better control on how many columns of data you want to display), as well as your own `BaseAdapter` class.

Here's an example.

First you need to do your `row_layout.xml` (create this in the layout folder) file, since you want each row to display a name and an age, this is what it would look like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ageTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="Age" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you have a row layout. I used the `weightSum` property so you're assured that your columns will split at half since the parent layout's weight is 100 and each of the textView (name and age) is at 50. You're allowed to change the textView's `layout_weight` as long as the total is the LinearLayout's `weightSum` which is 100.

Next, you need to make a BaseAdapter. This class handles how your listView populates the row layout.

Make a new class as such:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapterNameAndAge extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<NameAndAgeClass> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapterNameAndAge(Context context, ArrayList<NameAndAgeClass> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        //      int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout.xml, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            holder.age = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ageTextView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(listData.get(position).getName);
        holder.age.setText(listData.get(position).getAge));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView age;
    }

}
```

It may look like a mouthful but I'll break it down for you. The important part is the `getView` function where you get your layout file `row_layout.xml` and then get your holder object (see ViewHolder below), set the name and age TextViews based on your layoutfile, and then setting the values according to your `listData` ArrayList. The NameAndAgeClass Object is an object that you'll use to populate the list. In your case, it would have `name` and `age` as the private variables and then you'll have setters, getters, and constructors. I assume you know how to make that one already so I won't put in the code any more.

In your main activity, in your `onCreate()` function, do something like:

```
//instantiate your listView
ListView nameAndAgeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idOfYourListViewHere);

//create your listView with your custom object
ArrayList<NameAndAgeClass> nameAndAgeList = new ArrayList<>();

//
    IMPT, POPULTE THE ARRAYLIST HERE
    you can do a for loop or whatever you want
//

//create your adapter, use the nameAndAgeList ArrayList
CustomListViewAdapterNameAndAge nameAndAgeAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapterNameAndAge(this, nameAndAgeList);

//get your listView and use your adapter
nameAndAgeListView.setAdapter(nameAndAgeAdapter);
```

And that's it. Your app should show your data in a ListView with 2 columns.

After that, you can add an `onItemClickedListener` to your listView.

[Working Sample Here](https://www.mediafire.com/?5w71mz843ck0ni6)

Comment: Just ask if you need something clarified, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: i don't even know what question to ask lol, I'm like 20 errors a way from getting it to compiling, don't worry it's diffidently me not you! Hopefully I'll figure it out. I'm just going to give everyone a little bit in case there answering it, and if not I'll accept your answer, ty I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: can i ask for a example that compiles, I'm sorry to ask but I'm so lost, think you over estmated my abilitys lol. I never really worked with listviews much. Even if it just has 2 entry's phil 23 and bob 34. Idk how much work it is for you.  I'm sorry to be a pain, but I feel like if i ask you about every error I think i would be more work on your side,  I Think it would be good for other people that come across this to, just to have a nice example they can just tinker with also. If it's not a big pain. Ty!!!

Comment: Is it okay if I just edit my answer instead to be more straightforward?

Comment: Yea sure whatever is best for you, I really appreciate it, sorry i know it's not you, it's my lack of understanding!

Comment: Nevermind that, I'll just write a project in Android Studio and link you a zip file. Would that be ok?

Comment: Sure whatever is good for you, i don't want to be a pain, i know you went farther then most would. I was just kind of far from getting it to work.

Comment: @user3705179 here you go. https://www.mediafire.com/?5w71mz843ck0ni6 I can't seem to log into my GitHub account so I used mediafire instead

Comment: I asked a follow up question from this answer, how to make it dynamic, just in case you want to answer, figured it would be easier for you to answer then anyone.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406381/dynamic-custom-listview

Comment: Posted an answer in that question as well.